# C# accessing to oracle database using service id

Tags: c#, database, oracle, service, numbers

I am trying to login to my remote oracle database by giving user name, password, port number, service id and host name!

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            connectionString = "Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.25.72.90)(PORT = 1521))) " +
            " (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = SHARED) (SID = XE) )" +
        " ); User Id =" + uname.Text + "; password=" + pword.Text;


            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select DEFINITION_ID from ATS_AME_DEFS";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            label1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
        }
```

when I run the program I get an error "An unhandled exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll" at  "con.Open();"

But when I give service name as (SERVICE_NAME = ora12c) replacing the service id (SID = XE) I can access the database! How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle connection manager does not support **SID**, it only support **ServiceName**.

Comment: Thanx! What can I use to get support of service ID?